# Sticky footer inside a sticky footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

Environment: ASP.NET MVC 4, Visual Studio 2012

I have a "sticky footer" on my website that contains the usual copyright notice plus contact, privacy policy, etc. links (I've used the sticky footer code from http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).  The HTML that implements this scheme is in my site template (_Layout.cshtml).

Now, I have a web page that has some buttons on it that I want to render at the bottom of the page (just above the footer).  But I'm very new to this whole CSS thing, and I can't figure out how to structure my body HTML (and associated CSS) so that the body has its own sticky footer.

FYI, I'm not a stickler for using pure CSS to do this. Mine is a fairly special-purpose website, and I have no qualms requiring my customers to enable JavaScript.

For example:

+----------------------------------------------
| Page header, from _Layout.cshtml
+----------------------------------------------
| Page body, from my view
|
|
| Sticky "body" footer, from my view
+----------------------------------------------
| Page footer, from _Layout.cshtml
+----------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You can include the buttons which you want to render at the bottom of the page in a footer section so that along with the existing footer content these newly added buttons also would behave same manner.

Comment: That would be a great answer if I could get it to work.  Unfortunately, the "sticky footer" scheme relies on hard-coding the header height in the CSS.  Now, if someone could come up with a sticky footer that auto-sizes to match its content then I could solve a bunch of problems by including a magic Razor "section" that the View could use to insert content into the footer.